# How to remove duplicate paragraphs

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl, uniq

Given a file with paragraphs (group of lines separated by a blank line).
It is guaranteed that the line breaks within equivalent paragraphs are conserved.
Is there a way of using `uniq` to remove the duplicate paragraphs?

I suppose one could serialize each paragraph into a single line, perform `uniq` and
deserialize the result, is there a better solution?

Input:

```
Paragraph1
continue
continue

...

Paragraph2
continue
continue

...

Paragraph1
continue
continue

...

Paragraph2
continue
continue
```

Desired output: only one Paragraph1 and Paragraph2.

A command line solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `awk` documentation it seems that I could use the following:

```bsh
cat file.txt | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "\n\n+"; first = 1 } {if (!x[$0]++) { if (!first) {print ""}; print $0; first = 0} }'
```

Quick explanation:

- We set the record separator `RS` to "\n\n+" to separate paragraphs.
- The variable `first` is used to print a newline between records, alternatively you could print a newline after every $0, but then I didn't have a way of removing it for the last record.
- The map `x` is used to count if the record has been seen before, and only if it hasn't been seen will we print the record.
- If it is not the `first` record, we print a newline between records
- Print the record.
- Set `first` to False.

Comment: Or `awk -v RS= '! seen[$0]++ {print (NR == 1 ? "" : ORS) $0}' file.txt`. Logically similar, possibly a bit more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks that is indeed shorter, and I get to read about about ORS :)

Comment: That would require GNU awk for multi-char RS. Please also see http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html.

Comment: @EdMorton GNU awk is not the only awk which supports multi-char RS. First was mawk since a couple of DECADES ago, but now "bwk" (updated version of the original awk) does support it too. It's not the first time I see this bit of misinformation thrown around, it's high time to give up on it once for all.

Comment: @user414777 Yeah, you're right, I need to start saying something about it being non-POSIX rather than gawk-only.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!seen[$0]++' file
Paragraph1
continue
continue

...

Paragraph2
continue
continue
```